# spring boot data redis repository @Id annotation vs jpa repository @Id

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

I am using **spring boot 1.5.2**, and spring boot data redis 1.8 .

I have two @Id annotations, one is for JPA and another is for redis hash. Here I want to use JPA @Id value which is generated by mysql primary key AUTO_INCREMENT.

But I found that each time when I use redis @Id annotaion, in redis my id will be a another random value , but I want to use mysql primary key.

My Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@RedisHash(value = "order")
public class Order {
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;

    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id //for redis
    @Id //for mysql
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

My service like this:

```
@CachePut(value = "order", key = "#order.id")
@Override
public void save(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    try {
        Order order = BeanMapper.map(orderDTO, Order.class);
        order = orderRepository.save(order);
        System.out.println(order);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
```

the redis data like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "order"
2) "order:1222702657038933405"
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
order:12
```

which 12 is generated by mysql PRIMARY KEY.

I try to remove `@RedisHash` from `Order` found that cannot create cache for redis. I cannot find where is wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a key with whatever sequence you need to start with and increment the same before saving the new Key

1. [On the start of an application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4xrP.png)
2. [On save of each key value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq1q7.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Just copy-paste the code directly into your answer.